# Multithreading string processing

Tags: java, multithreading

Let me describe my problem: I need to upload file through browser, and go through that file and find all unique word with their positions (first and last position, distance between those etc.) and I need to do that using multithreading. The truth is I never used multithreading but I have been reading a lot about it and I can't make a clear idea how to do it.

I have done all those thing in single thread (well pure Java without any `Runnable` or `Thread`) like this:

- Load file to string
- Clean string from special characters and split it by whitespaces
- Find all positions (occurances) of each word and put it to HashMap

So all of this needs to be concurrent. I don't know how to do it with multithreading. I just need some idea what to do, I can't wrap my mind around this concurrent programming.

Comment: Why does it have to be concurrent? Also, writing an entire tutorial on multi threading is asking a bit much of us ...

Comment: The thing is, task is to do it with multithreading, for a job interview. I can't see any gain in doing this using multi threading at all.

Comment: Honestly, go buy a copy of 'Java Concurrency in Practice'. This is an enormous topic that even explaining to at a high level to go about your specific task doesn't really help because of the complexity involved (in terms of Java's memory model).

Comment: @BrianRoach I know this is a bit too broad question, but I haven't got any idea in two days on what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-threading lets you break up a task into components that can be run simultaneously. These components are usually independent of each other. In your case, the third step can be done independently for each word once the characters have been split. Here is an example of how you could implement your task using threads:

1. Load the file to string
2. Clean string from special characters and split it by whitespaces
3. Put the result into a [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)
4. Create a [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) to put your final results into
5. Start as many threads as you need/like

Within each thread, you will do the following:

1. Get an item from the queue
2. If there are no more items, die
3. Otherwise, find the position of the word and put it into the hash map

You will probably want to extend the `Thread` class or implement `Runnable` for the concurrent functionality.

Comment: You probably want to see [`ExecutorService`](http://download.java.net/lambda/b88/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and drop creating `Thread`s manually.

Comment: And rarely if ever should you extend `Thread`

Comment: Ok, I could go with this idea. Thanks.